# Tell Laravel / Nginx to use proxy

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, proxy

**Solved i just had to declare in the code to use proxy, see comments below @apokryfos got it right**

Hi i am hosting the website using Nginx, mysql and php7.2 website is using laravel framework. The server has only access to the internet trough proxy, i have set the proxy config for all users like this in:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And here is how the file looks:

```
administrator@orion:/var/www/truckstock$ sudo nano /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/>
http_proxy=http://10.254.234.70:3128/
https_proxy=https://10.254.234.70:3128/
```

For all the purposes like setting up server using git, composer... proxy works like a charm.

The problem comes up when i user who is visting website tries to query external API ( Our website needs to get some data from [Monday.com](https://monday.com) )  which is [api2.monday.com](https://api2.monday.com) the connection just doesn't work and on my local server ( My Laptop ) everything works fine.

My question is how can i tell Nginx or Laravel or Php ( Not sure who is making this request ) to use porxy?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1:**  Here is how the part of the code doing the api query looks

```
 $query = 'mutation {
change_column_value (board_id: 570045226, item_id: '.$id.', column_id: "status", value: "{\"index\": 11}") {
id
}
}';
    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json', 'User-Agent: [MYTEAM] GraphQL Client', 'Authorization: ' . $token];
    $data = @file_get_contents($tempUrl, false, stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => $headers,
            'content' => json_encode(['query' => $query]),
        ]
    ]));
    $tempContents = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: You should be sure you is making the request. It's probably done in code somewhere, maybe it's using something like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or similar. You should contact the developer of the site who is the one who's supposed to solve this issue

Comment: @apokryfos Hi am the developer and i need to set proxy, but i dont know how, see the edit that i posted that is how i am contacting api.

Comment: A comment in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php does describe a way to use a proxy

Comment: Hi thanks a lot mate i will try it out tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot mate this solved my issue @apokryfos

Comment: You could answer your question with what you did in case others find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what i did was i changed this code:

```
 $query = 'mutation {
change_column_value (board_id: 570045226, item_id: '.$id.', column_id: "status", value: "{\"index\": 11}") {
id
}
}';
    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json', 'User-Agent: [MYTEAM] GraphQL Client', 'Authorization: ' . $token];
    $data = @file_get_contents($tempUrl, false, stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => $headers,
            'content' => json_encode(['query' => $query]),
        ]
    ]));
    $tempContents = json_decode($data, true);
```

And i added proxy information so it came like this:

```
$query = 'mutation {
    change_column_value (board_id: 570045226, item_id: '.$id.', column_id: "status", value: "{\"index\": 11}") {
    id
    }
    }';
        $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json', 'User-Agent: [MYTEAM] GraphQL Client', 'Authorization: ' . $token];
        $data = @file_get_contents($tempUrl, false, stream_context_create([
            'http' => [
                'proxy' => 'my proxy', 
                 'request_fulluri' => true
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => $headers,
                'content' => json_encode(['query' => $query]),
            ]
        ]));
        $tempContents = json_decode($data, true);
```